# Can I read property file with jetty in development?

Tags: scala, properties, jetty, lift

I am working on a lift project as a sub-project in a gigantic mvn project. I put the property files into:

- src/main/resources/props/staging.props
- src/main/resources/props/production.props

in the sub-project folder.

Then I run jetty with:

```
mvn jetty:run -Drun.mode=staging
```

I printed out the settings from `net.liftweb.util.Props` using:

```
println("file_name:" + Props.fileName)
println("mode_name:" + Props.modeName)
```

The output:

```
file_name:lift.props
mode_name:staging
```

The mode name is correct. However, the file name is totally wrong. `net.liftweb.util.Props` is still using the file name that had been hardcoded in the source. It seemed never reached my property file.

Am I missing something? Or it cannot work with jetty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [duffymo is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006616/115478) and you can just use the underlying servlet facilities for getting resources, I would still use [Lift's Properties abstraction](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Properties). It already does the work for differentiating different [run modes](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Run_Modes). It also allows you to have different properties per-user and/or per-machine, which can be useful, depending on your development team.

The default properties for a given mode should be put in `/props/modeName.default.props`, so your files should be renamed to:

- `src/main/resources/props/staging.default.props`
- `src/main/resources/props/production.default.props`

Answer (score 2):

I would put the .properties file in your /WEB-INF/classes and use the servlet context's `getResourceAsStream()` to read it in.

Comment: Is there any particular reason not using lift's Props? Or it's just not that stable?

Comment: Don't know about lift; I do know how to make stuff available in a web app.